# On triangular decomposition of square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $L\in Gl_n(\mathbb{C})$ and define $A=LL^*$. Let us consider another decomposition such as $A=L_1L_1^*$. What is the relation between $L$ and $L_1$. One obvious relation is $L_1=LU$ where $U$ is an unitary operator. Is it the only relation between them? How to prove that?

One more thing: Since $A>0$ it has a unique [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) $A=T.T^*$ where $T$ is an upper triangular matrix. Moreover we can have a [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of $L=VSV^*$, where $S$ is upper triangular matrix. What can be the relation between $T$ and $S$? This probably means to calculate the following:

Given fixed upper triangular matrix $T$ determine $\{(S,U_1,U_2): T=U_1SU_2,~~U_i,U_2\in U(n) $ and $S$ is an upper triangular matrix$\}$.

It will be of great help if someone can point out any hint suggestion etc. Advanced thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for first question:

If you have $L L^* = L_1 L_1^*$, then $(L_1^{-1} L) (L_1^{-1} L)^* = I$, hence $L_1^{-1} L$ is unitary. Similarly, if $A = L L^*$, and $U$ is unitary, then $A=(LU) (LU)^*$.

Comment: actually what i wanted was the converse statement, which is:- if the above relation $LL^*=L_1L_1^*$ holds, then $L=L_1U$, where $U$ is unitary is `the only' relation between $L$ and $L_1$. One more thing. I want to take Schur decomposition of $L$ not $A$. $L$ need not be even a diagonalisable matrix (example a Jordan block).

Comment: What do you mean by 'the only' relationship? I showed that if $L L^* = L_1 L_1^*$ then $L_1^{-1} L$ is unitary, and also, if $A=L L^*$ and $U$ is unitary, then $A = (LU) (LU)^*$.

Comment: I removed my second comment, I completely missed the fact that you were using the Schur decomposition of $L$.

Comment: Not sure this deserved an accept.